# C++ Container defined in construction

Tags: c++, templates

I might be asking this question in the wrong way, but I want to define a member container on instantiation of the object.

```
namespace GUI {

class MenuNode {
    template <typename TMenuItem>
    struct MenuItem{
        TMenuItem *text;
    };
    MenuItem<unknown> t;//The member where I want the container
                        //to be defined upon construction
public:
    std::vector<MenuNode*> forward;
    MenuNode* parent;
    MenuNode();
    ~MenuNode();
};
}
```

One way I could AVOID this problem is to make MenuNode a template class itself, but I'll have forward and backward pointers with required containers(linked list style) and I will not know their container types either!

```
namespace GUI {
template<class MenuItem>
class MenuNode {
    MenuItem t;
public:
    std::vector<MenuNode<unknown>*> forward;    //Here I wouldn't know
                                                //what the container will
                                                //even be!
    MenuNode<unknown>* parent;        //same with this member
    MenuNode();
    ~MenuNode();
};
}
```

So an alternative would be having a pointer type that could point to an address regardless of the member's container

```
namespace GUI {
template<class MenuItem>
class MenuNode {
    MenuItem t;
public:
    std::vector<void*> forward;
    void* parent;     
    MenuNode();
    ~MenuNode();
};
}
```

But The problem with void pointers is I don't know how I would determine what type of container the object is holding! Plus I have never used a void pointer!

If the solution is to use void pointers if I create MenuItems that have very similar functions (same names) can I call them through a dereference to the void pointer(s).

Comment: One alternative is using [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) if you're using c++17, or `boost::any` if you're not. There's also `std::variant` (c++17) and `boost::variant` if you know all the types ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an abstract base class. Here is a sketch:

```
class MenuNodeBase {
    std::vector<MenuNodeBase *> forward;
    MenuNodeBase *parent;
    virtual ~MenuNodeBase() = default;
};

template<class T>
class MenuNode : public MenuNodeBase {
    MenuItem<T> t;
};
```

You can use virtual functions or `dynamic_cast` to access functionality of the concrete class.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If you edit an answer so soon after it's posted you're going to run into edit conflicts with the poster, like what happened here.